# Temporary failure resolving 'repo.jellyfin.org' with correct resolv.conf config ubuntu

Tags: dns

i am a noob so please provide answer accordingly
i am using a mini pc as a jellyfin server with remote.it , it was working great until i tried installing nextcloud and when i was away on a trip my server stopped responding to sudo apt update
and giving name resolution issue i tried everything on the internet to solve the issue .
the resolv.conf file looks like this

```
# Generated by dhcpcd from enp2s0.dhcp, enp2s0.dhcp6, enp2s0.ra
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver fd75:beba:8d64::1
# /etc/resolv.conf.tail can replace this line
```

```
sudo apt update
Err:1 https://repo.jellyfin.org/ubuntu groovy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'repo.jellyfin.org'
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu groovy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/groovy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://repo.jellyfin.org/ubuntu/dists/groovy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'repo.jellyfin.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu/dists/groovy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

```
 ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=2.62 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=119 time=2.23 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=119 time=2.33 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=119 time=2.16 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.158/2.332/2.620/0.176 ms
```

```
 ping -c4 google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

i have no vnc or remote desktop service so solutions using terminal would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 groovy

Comment: OK the references to archive were confusing.

Comment: sorry it is my first post it is a bit cluttered but i have searched for a solution in every forum i could find

Comment: i have commented out all the ubuntu sources.list link as i thought those were corrupted links.